# question in probability problem

Tags: probability

good day! I need your help! can you help me with this kind of probability problem:

> A box contains 5 red balls, 4 green balls, 6 yellow balls. If those balls are drawn from the box in succession, what is the probability of getting balls on:
>
> 1. ball's of the same color
> 2. 2 red, 1 green ball
> 3. 3 green or 3 yellow balls

please do help me on this.
need it right away.
thank you very much

Comment: You seem to be missing several important words.  How many balls are being drawn?  Have you ever heard of the multiplication principle of probability?  Have you ever heard of a tree diagram?

Comment: A box contains 5 red, 4 green and 6 yellow balls. If 3 balls are drawn in succession, what is the probability of getting

A. Balls of the same color
B. 2 red and 1 green balls
C. 3 green or 3 yellow balls

Comment: A box contains 5 red, 4 green and 6 yellow balls. If 3 balls are drawn in succession, what is the probability of getting

A. Balls of the same color
B. 2 red and 1 green balls
C. 3 green or 3 yellow balls

Comment: For (A), do you want the probability for (1a) All balls of the same colour, or (1b) At least two balls of the same colour?   You still have not indicate *how many* balls are being drawn.

Comment: (A). (1a) all tree balls of the same color. pls do help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > A box contains 5 red balls, 4 green balls, 6 yellow balls. If three from those balls are drawn from the box in succession, what is the probability for getting :
>
> 1. Three balls all of the same colour.

What is the probability for drawing $3$ from $5$ red, *or* $3$ from $4$ green, *or* $3$ from $6$ yellow, when drawing any $3$ from all $15$ balls?

> 2. 2 red, 1 green ball.

What is the probability for drawing $2$ from $5$ red *and* $1$ from $4$ green when drawing any $3$ from all $15$ balls.

> 3. $3$ green or $3$ yellow balls.

See $1.$

---

Remember that $\dbinom nk$ counts the selections of $k$ elements from a set of $n$.   This is sometimes written as ${}^n\mathrm C_k$ and equals $\dfrac{n!}{k!~(n-k)!}$

Comment: the answer would be? thats the right question

Answer (score 0):

Let’s take a look at a different question and hopefully you can generalize the method to your problem.

Suppose I have a bag with $\color{red}{\text{3 red}}$ balls, $\color{blue}{\text{4 blue}}$ balls and $\color{green}{\text{3 green}}$ balls.  Suppose I draw two balls in succession independently and uniformly at random without replacement.

I ask myself, what is the probability of drawing a $\color{red}{\text{red }}$ball and a $\color{green}{\text{green ball}}$ in either order.

To do this, either we get a red ball followed by a green ball, or we get a green ball followed by a red ball.  Letting $C_i$ represent drawing a ball of color $C$ in the $i$'th draw (*e.g. $R_1$ represents drawing a red ball in the first draw*)

The probability of a red ball followed by a green ball is $Pr(R_1\cap G_2)=Pr(R_1)Pr(G_2\mid R_1) = \frac{\color{red}{3}}{\color{red}{3}+\color{blue}{4}+\color{green}{3}} \cdot \frac{\color{green}{3}}{\color{red}{2}+\color{blue}{4}+\color{green}{3}}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}=0.1$

Meanwhile the probability of a green ball followed by a red ball is $Pr(G_1\cap R_2)=Pr(G_1)Pr(R_2\mid G_1) = \frac{\color{green}{3}}{\color{red}{3}+\color{blue}{4}+\color{green}{3}} \cdot \frac{\color{red}{3}}{\color{red}{3}+\color{blue}{4}+\color{green}{2}}=\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}=0.1$

Adding, we get $Pr(\text{Green and Red})=Pr(R_1\cap G_2)+Pr(G_1\cap R_2)=0.1+0.1=0.2$

At each step in the calculation, to calculate the respective probabilities or conditional probabilities count how many balls of the desired color there are still remaining in the box and divide by the total number of balls still remaining in the box.